# Filter in ggplot2's geoms using common aesthetics and data frames across geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have the following data frame:

```
# Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5, 2), y = runif(10), z = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5))

#    x          y z
# 1  1 0.92024937 A
# 2  2 0.37246007 A
# 3  3 0.76632809 A
# 4  4 0.03418754 A
# 5  5 0.33770400 A
# 6  1 0.15367174 B
# 7  2 0.78498276 B
# 8  3 0.03341913 B
# 9  4 0.77484244 B
# 10 5 0.13309999 B
```

I'd like to plot cases where `z == "A"` as points and cases where `z == "B"` as lines. Simple enough.

```
library(ggplot2)
# Plot data
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_point(data = df %>% filter(z == "A"), aes(x = x, y = y))
g <- g + geom_line(data = df %>% filter(z == "B"), aes(x = x, y = y))
g
```

[image]

My data frame and aesthetic for the points and lines are identical, so this seems a bit verbose – especially if I want to do this lots of times (e.g., `z == "A"` through `z == "Z"`). Is there a way that I could state `ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))` and then subsequently state my filtering or subsetting criteria within the appropriate geoms?

Comment: You can use `ggplot(mapping=aes(x = x, y = y))` to avoid repeating the `aes()`. But you'll need to do repeat the data.frame name in each of the geoms. Are you really plotting a different geom for each level of z? Hard to image how this scales to more levels. It's possible to automate this stuff with your own function of course. But maybe an example that's closer to what you are really trying to do would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot lines and points for all `z` records, but remove unwanted lines and points with passing `NA` to `scale_linetype_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, linetype = z, shape = z)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, NA)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA, 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Super sleek. I'd use named vectors for the values in each scale just to make sure you're getting the right combinations of `z` and `NA`

Answer (score 6):

I find the example in the question itself the most readable, although verbose. The second part of the question about dealing with more cases just requires a more sophisticated test in `filter` using for example `%in%` (or `grep`, `grepl`, etc.) when dealing with multiple cases. Taking advantage of the possibility of accessing default plot data within a layer, and as mentioned by @MrFlick moving the mapping of aesthetics out of the individual layers results in more concise code. All earlier answers get the plot done, so in this respect my answer is not better than any of them...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5, 4), 
                 y = runif(20), 
                 z = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "Z"), each = 5))

g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(z %in% c("A", "B", "C"))) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(z == "Z"))
g
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to `spread` the data and then just supply the y aesthetic.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% spread(z,y) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x))+
    geom_point(aes(y = A))+
    geom_line(aes(y = B))
```

Comment: An update for more recent versions of tidyr is to use `pivot_wider` as `spread` has been superseded `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "z", values_from = "y")`